# nested struct in c, problem with addressing pointers

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I have a programming exercise, in which I have to make two structures: `Star` and `Cluster`. `Star` has to take four arguments - name, 1st number, 2nd number, 3rd number. `Cluster` contains n - Stars which are in the file **stars.dat** and information about file name from which the star is. Then write a load function which takes file as an argument and returns a pointer to a `Cluster` structure read from a file. My code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME 100

struct Star {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    double recta;
    double decl;
    double mag;
};

struct Cluster {
    struct Star *ptr;
    char *file;
};

struct Cluster *load(char *plik);

int main() {
    load("stars.dat");
    return 0;
}

struct Cluster *load(char *plik) {
    char line[MAX_NAME];
    int i = 0;
    struct Star *star_ptr;

    FILE *file = fopen(plik, "r");
    struct Cluster *cluster_ptr;
    if (!plik) {
        perror(plik);
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        while (fgets(line, MAX_NAME, file) != NULL) {
            star_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Star));
            sscanf(line, "%s %lf %lf %lf", star_ptr->name, &star_ptr->recta, &star_ptr->decl, &star_ptr->mag);

            printf("%s \n", star_ptr->name);
            star_ptr++;
            i++;
        }
        cluster_ptr = (struct Cluster *)malloc(sizeof(struct Star) * i);
        cluster_ptr->ptr = star_ptr;
        cluster_ptr->file = plik;
        // printf("%s \n", cluster_ptr->star_ptr[0].name);
        printf("%s \n", star_ptr[0].name);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return cluster_ptr;
}
```

My question is if this is a proper way to do this? How can I check if returned pointer is good (I can't figure out how to `printf` for example name of the 1st star in a list). Would appreciate if someone could give me a hint.

Comment: I have now given you several hints in my answer. Would you like me to change your code so that it uses a linked list?

Comment: I would appreciate that, I changed my code so now I can access every element of `Struct Cluster` but in my solution I predefined array with a given size which doesn't seem right.

Comment: If you want to use arrays instead of a linked list, one thing you could do is to first go through the entire input file once in order to count the number of stars. That way, you will know how large the array must be. Then you can go back to the start of the file using [`fseek`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) and read the individual stars. However, this is not necessary if you use a linked list instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handling of the `struct Cluster` member variable `struct Star *ptr` does not make sense.

If you want `struct Cluster` to be able to "contain" multiple `struct Star`, then you could for example do one of the following:

1. Make `struct Cluster` contain a pointer that points to the first element of a dynamically allocated [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) of data type `struct Star`.
2. Make `struct Cluster` contain an array or have a member pointer that points to a dynamically allocated array of elements of type `struct Star`. In order to keep track of the number of elements in this array, you will additionally need a separate member variable.
3. Make `struct Cluster` contain an array or have a member pointer that points to a dynamically allocated array of elements of type `struct Star*`, where each element is a pointer to its own dynamically allocated `struct Star`. In order to keep track of the number of elements in this array, you could either have a separate variable which specifies the number of elements or you could mark the end of the array with a special value, for example a `NULL` pointer.

Your code does neither of these options. Instead, you do the following:

For every star you find in the file, you dynamically allocate enough memory for one single `struct Star`. But instead of remembering the memory address of this `struct Star`, in the next iteration of the loop, you overwrite the pointer to this memory address with the memory address of the next `struct Star`, so that you no longer know the address of the first `struct Star`.  This is a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Ater the last iteration of the loop finishes, you then make the cluster's `ptr` member point to the last `struct Star` that was allocated, so that it is effectively pointing to only one star. It cannot be pointing to more stars, because, as I have already pointed out, you did not remember their memory locations.

Therefore, in order to fix your problem, I recommend that you decide which of the options listed above you want to use and write your code accordingly. If you do not know in advance the number of stars in a cluster, I recommend that you first try option #1 (the linked list).

Also, the following line contains a bug:

`if (!plik)`

You should change it to the following:

`if (!file)`

Or maybe to this, which I personally consider more readable:

`if ( file == NULL )`

EDIT: Because you stated in the comments section that you wanted an example for a linked list implementation, I have modified your code accordingly and posted it below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

//Do not change the following line without also changing MAX_NAME_MINUS_ONE_STRING
#define MAX_NAME 100
#define MAX_NAME_MINUS_ONE_STRING "99"
//the line above must have the value MAX_NAME - 1 and be enclosed in quotation
//marks, otherwise you risk a buffer overflow in the sscanf function call!

struct StarNode
{
    //this points to the next node of the linked list
    struct StarNode *next;

    //I changed this struct member to a pointer to a dynamically
    //allocated string, because having a char array of 100 bytes
    //was a waste of memory
    char *name;

    double recta;
    double decl;
    double mag;
};

struct Cluster
{
    //points to the head of the linked list of stars
    struct StarNode *p_head;

    //points to its own dynamically allocated copy of the filename
    char *filename;
};

struct Cluster* load_cluster( const char* filename );
void cleanup_cluster( struct Cluster *p_cluster );

int main()
{
    struct Cluster *cluster_ptr;

    cluster_ptr = load_cluster( "stars.dat" );

    cleanup_cluster( cluster_ptr );

    return 0;
}

struct Cluster* load_cluster( const char *filename )
{
    char line[MAX_NAME];

    //pp_next will always point to the address of the struct StarNode * where
    //the address of the next node should be written
    struct StarNode *p_newstar, **pp_next;
    struct Cluster *p_cluster;

    FILE *file = fopen( filename, "r" );
    assert( file != NULL );

    p_cluster = (struct Cluster*)malloc( sizeof( struct Cluster ) );
    assert( p_cluster != NULL );

    pp_next = &p_cluster->p_head;

    while ( fgets( line, MAX_NAME, file ) != NULL )
    {
        char starname[MAX_NAME];
        int i;

        p_newstar = (struct StarNode *)malloc( sizeof( struct StarNode ) );
        assert( p_newstar != NULL );

        //I changed the %s to %99s (assuming MAX_NAME == 100) to prevent buffer overflow.
        //The value must be one less in order to have space for the null terminator.
        //Also, I now check the return value of sscanf.
        i = sscanf( line, "%" MAX_NAME_MINUS_ONE_STRING "s %lf %lf %lf", starname, &p_newstar->recta, &p_newstar->decl, &p_newstar->mag );
        assert( i == 4 );

        printf( "Adding %s\n", starname );

        //allocate memory for star's own copy of starname and copy it
        p_newstar->name = (char*)malloc( strlen( starname ) + 1 /*for null terminator character*/ );
        assert( p_newstar->name != NULL );
        strcpy( p_newstar->name, starname );

        //link the new star node to the linked list
        *pp_next = p_newstar;

        //update pp_next to the address of the pointer where the address of the next node should be written to
        pp_next = &p_newstar->next;
    }

    //the last element of the linked list must have a NULL pointer
    *pp_next = NULL;

    //allocate sufficient memory for filename and copy the string
    p_cluster->filename = (char*)malloc( strlen( filename ) + 1 /*for null terminator character*/ );
    assert( p_cluster->filename != NULL );
    strcpy( p_cluster->filename, filename );

    fclose( file );
    return p_cluster;
}


void cleanup_cluster( struct Cluster *p_cluster )
{
    struct StarNode *p;

    p = p_cluster->p_head;

    //cleanup every star node individually
    while ( p != NULL )
    {
        struct StarNode *temp;

        printf( "Deleting %s\n", p->name );
        free( p->name );

        temp = p;
        p = p->next;
        //free must be called last, because the contents of the current node become invalid
        //once free is called, which means that also the pointer to the next node would
        //become invalid
        free( temp );
    }

    free( p_cluster->filename );

    free( p_cluster );
}
```

In the code above, I also created a function `cleanup_cluster` in order to free the memory allocated by a cluster.

Please note that I also changed the line

`cluster_ptr->file = plik;`

so that the cluster struct stores its own copy of the string. This has the advantage that you can also pass strings with a limited lifetime (such as local char arrays) to the function without the pointer becoming a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

Comment: Thank you for your solution, that helped a lot. Why didn't you have to dynamically alocate memory for other variables (you allocated it only for name). Is it because type double takes always same size?

Comment: Yes, dynamic memory allocation only makes sense for the string, because its length is unknown. The size of a `double` is always known, so it makes sense for it to be directly contained in the struct.

Comment: The `double` actually is also dynamically allocated, but it is allocated as part of its owning struct (which is also dynamically allocated) instead of being seperately allocated like the string.

Comment: @Konrad: I hope you are not too confused by my use of a double pointer, i.e. a pointer to a pointer. It is possible to use simple pointers instead, but this would require an additional `if` statement to determine whether you are at the start of the list or not. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60917667/) (which also contains an answer of mine) for more information. It is C++, not C, though. I believe that my answer to this question demonstrates that using double pointers are more efficient.