# How to make a singly linked list based on inputs

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm just learning linked lists, and want to make one with inputs from the console, but somehow it's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct datatype Node;
struct datatype {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int main() {

    int i,n;
    Node *node[50];

    printf("Number of intergers: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter interger one by one: ");
        scanf("%d",&node[i]->data);
        node[i]->next=node[i+1];
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d->",node[i]->data);
}
```

Comment: You must allocate memory for the individual nodes of the linked list. Instead, you are allocating memory for 50 pointers to individual nodes, but not for the nodes themselves. I suggest you use the function [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) for this.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thank you so much. So you have to use malloc for each node, thanks for the knowledge!

Comment: Just as a side note: You should always check the return value of `scanf` before using any of the values you receive from it. See this page for further information: [A beginner's guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Andreas's comment, here is a commented and memory safe implementation. You don't necessarily have to use malloc and free; you could instead have a fixed memory pool:

```
#define MAX_NODE_SIZE 256

...

Node node[MAX_NODE_SIZE];
```

followed by a check  to make sure the user never puts n greater than MAX_NODE_SIZE. However if you tried to implement list inserts and deletes things would get complicated. Also, using an index "i" to iterate through a linked list kind of defeats the point of having a linked list.

Here is the malloc/free version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct datatype Node;
struct datatype {
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

int main() {
    //Allocate the root node
    Node *rootnode=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    rootnode->data=0; rootnode->next=NULL; 
    Node *currentnode=rootnode;

    //Populate n and check for validity
    printf("Number of integers: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    if(n<=0){
        printf("List must have a nonzero/nonnegative number of elements.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Populate the list
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter integer one by one: ");
        scanf("%d",&currentnode->data);
        //If there is more data...
        if(i!=n-1){
            //Allocate room for the data
            currentnode->next=malloc(sizeof(Node));
            //Initialize things correctly
            currentnode->next->data=0;
            currentnode->next->next=NULL;
            //Step to the next node.
            currentnode=currentnode->next;
        }
    }

    //Print the list
    currentnode=rootnode;
    do {
        printf("%d",currentnode->data);
        if(currentnode->next!=NULL)
            printf(" -> ");
        else
            printf("\n");
    } while((currentnode=currentnode->next)!=NULL);

    //Deallocate the list
    currentnode=rootnode;
    while(currentnode!=NULL){
        Node *next=currentnode->next;
        free(currentnode);
        currentnode=next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
user@desktop:~$ ./a.out
Number of integers: 3
Enter integer one by one: 1
Enter integer one by one: 2
Enter integer one by one: 3
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Comment: What I don't like about your code is that you assume that there is at least one node, so that you can preallocate memory for the root node. Also, due to this preallocation, in every loop iteration, you must check for both `n` and for `n - 1`.Therefore, I have created an alternative answer. My answer uses double pointers so that the pointer to the root node can be handled like any other node pointer. That way, my program also handles the case of 0 nodes without any additional code. Also, I only have to perform one check per loop iteration, because I don't need to preallocate a node.

Comment: I realize that many people find double-pointers confusing. However, in this case, they are very efficient, because they allow the root pointer to be handled like any other pointer in the linked list.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel it seems like the complexity of `if(i!=n-1)` is just moved into `Node **ppNext`, so it's a tradeoff between extra state or extra if statements. I sided on less state in my code. But I agree both approaches are interesting.

Comment: You also have code duplicaton. Your code for allocating the root node is separate from the code which allocates the remaining nodes. In my solution, the same code is used for allocating all of the nodes. Personally, I believe an additional pointer is a small price to pay for this simplicity. However, the main disadvantage of my solution is that many people find double-pointers hard to understand, as I have previously experienced with my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60917667/12149471).

Comment: @andreaswenzel I don't consider two mallocs code duplication.

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is bad. However, in my opinion, using a double-pointer is so much more elegant in this situation that I felt compelled to write my own alternative answer. In this respect, I feel [the same way as Linus Torvalds](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/). You are of course free to disagree with me and Linus.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Hm, I agree to my dismay! Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate memory for the individual nodes of the linked list. Instead, you are allocating memory for 50 pointers to individual nodes, but not for the nodes themselves.

I suggest you create a standard linked list and use the function [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) for the individual nodes, like this:

```
typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

int main( void )
{
    //this pointer always points to the first element, or NULL if there is no first element
    Node *pRoot = NULL;

    //this pointer always points to the NULL pointer at the end of the list, which is, when the list is empty, the root pointer
    Node **ppNext = &pRoot;

    Node *pCurrent;
    int retval, n;

    //ask user for total number of data elements
    printf( "Number of integers: " );
    retval = scanf( "%d", &n );
    if ( retval != 1)
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed!\n" );
        goto cleanup;
    }

    //build the list from user input
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        //allocate memory for new node
        pCurrent = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
        if ( pCurrent == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "malloc failed!\n" );
            goto cleanup;
        }

        //ask user for individual data elements
        printf( "Enter integer one by one: " );
        retval = scanf( "%d", &pCurrent->data );
        if ( retval != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed!\n" );
            free( pCurrent );
            goto cleanup;
        }
        pCurrent->next = NULL;

        //link new node to linked list and update ppNext
        *ppNext = pCurrent;
        ppNext = &pCurrent->next;
    }

    //print the list
    for ( pCurrent = pRoot; pCurrent != NULL; pCurrent = pCurrent->next )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", pCurrent->data );
    }

cleanup:

    //free the linked list
    for ( pCurrent = pRoot; pCurrent != NULL; )
    {
        Node *tmp = pCurrent;
        pCurrent = pCurrent->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that in my code, before I use the value written to by `scanf`, I check the return value of `scanf`. This is necessary because the function may fail and not write any value, for example when the user enters letters instead of numbers. See this page for further information:

[A beginner's guide away from `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)